# Different BFF / endpoints for a i18n Nextjs application with react-query and Axios

Tags: next.js, axios, internationalization, react-query, i18next

I'm building Nextjs application using the native i18n nextjs module, and i18next + next-i18next libraries for supporting me.

My question is, we are going to have 2 differentes BFF's, one for each language, and do something like that:

```js
const ENDPOINTS = {
    en: 'https://url-for-en-bff/',
    es: 'https://url-for-es-bff/'
}

const Home: NextPage = (props) => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation(['common']);

    useEffect(() => { //ignore eslint problem
        await fetch(ENDPOINTS[i18n.resolvedLanguage]).then(() => //something else)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div>
                <h1 className={styles.title}>{t('content')}</h1>
                <Image src={image1} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(ctx.locale as any, ['common'])),
        },
    };
};

export default Home;
```

Where I will conditionally choose conditionally my endpoint at a runtime in a component level, repeting myself for every component and maybe compromising some performance, for sure is not the best pratice to do it...

I'm gonna have some hooks (react-query) that call some endpoints too for reuse in some components... So, there is a scope question when getting my language

I thought about some:

- Middleware at axios where i get my current language and change de domain, but, I dont know how get the language at this scope
- Some BFF with next, considering that next has the current language at context
- Next.js Middleware? I dont know
- Different builds with domaind at env.var, but, that would be my last options...

So, anyone had this trouble?

I tried to config a middleware at axios, but I didn't figured it out how I could acess my language at this scope level, outsite components e etc

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/issues/114